# Why does $x= (5/3)$ behave the same as $x=(-5/-3)$ in the equation $2x + 3 = 5x - 2$?

Tags: algebras

Solving for $x$ in the original equation $(2x + 3 = 5x - 2)$ I got $-5/-3$, but the video I was watching from got the value $5/3$. Checking the correctness, I substituted my answer and got $0$ on both ends, meaning that the two expressions were equal. Can someone please explain why the negative gives the same result as the positive?

Comment: $\dfrac{-5}{-3} = \dfrac{-5 \times -1}{-3 \times -1} = \dfrac{5}{3}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negatives cancel out.  This is the same thing as saying $$\require{cancel}
\frac{\cancel{(-1)}(5)}{\cancel{(-1)}(3)}$$

Remember, a negative times a negative is positive, and likewise, a negative divided by a negative is positive.

Answer (score 1):

A debt of \$5 is almost twice as much as a debt of \$3, just as a deposit of \$5 is almost twice as much as a deposit of \$3.  The ratios are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Two rational numbers $a/b$ and $c/d$ ($a,b,c,d$ integers, $b\ne0$ and $d\ne0$) are equal if and only if
$$
ad=bc
$$
By definition, I should add.

Comment: I see. It follows the rule and that makes it correct. Thanks